# Eclipse Javascript Editor 2012 with full Outliner support

Tags: javascript, eclipse, codehighlighter, outliner, object-notation

The reason for using an `IDE` is the comprehensive facilities it provides.

Therefore, I assume there is a `Javascript` editor for Eclipse that provides basic outliner-based `IDE` facilities such as:

- **Outliner** with `Object Literal` support (which apparently is rare)
- Intelligent **Code Completion** using `Outliner` data
- Intelligent **Code Highlighting** using `Outliner` data, not just similar words
- Inter-file scoping (`@include "otherfile.js"`)

However, for `Javascript`, these features seem scattered across multiple editors:

- [Amateras Javascript Editor](http://amateras.sourceforge.jp/cgi-bin/fswiki_en/wiki.cgi)
      + **Inter-file scoping** (uses external files automatically from certain code constructs)
      - No code highlighting
      - No object literal outlining
- [Javascript Editor](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jsdt/) (Eclipse WDT JSDT)
      + **Intelligent code highlighting** for reads and writes
      - No inter-file scoping
      - No object literal outlining
- [Javascript Source Editor](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/download) (Aptana plugin)
      + **Object Literal is outlined fully**
      - Fake (similar word) code highlighting
      - No inter-file scoping
- [Spket Javascript Editor](http://www.spket.com/javascript-editor.html)
      ~ **Object Literal is outlined partially**
      - Fake (similar word different vars) code highlighting
      - No inter-file scoping
- [VJET Ebay Open Source Javascript Editor](https://www.ebayopensource.org/index.php/VJET/HomePage)
      - [I can't get it to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12072633/how-do-i-properly-run-the-vjet-development-tools-for-nodejs-on-eclipse), but it's supposed to be one of the better projects.

Javascript is a very popular language, and more and more frameworks such as `ExtJS` rely solely on JSON-*like* `Object Notation`.

Are there any `Javascript` editors for Eclipse that provide full Outliner-support? How else do these developers (e.g. for `ExtJS`) facilitate their `Javascript` development for modern frameworks?

Although lacking specifics, this is a good and popular question in general that is yet to be answered to satisfaction:

- [Javascript Editor '08](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24678/eclipse-javascript-editor)
- [Javascript Editor '10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025444/eclipse-javascript-editor-10)

*Note that devs depend on an `IDE` by preference and dependence on other `Eclipse` plugins such as the [Chome Developer Tools](https://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools/) and the `V8 Debugger`. Therefore, the scope of this question is **Eclipse plugins only**.*

Comment: Sorry, we specifically discourage questions which ask for product recommendations.  They attract spam and link rot.  If it gets reopened by vote a mod will most likely close it again.

Comment: That's unfortunate, because I've asked and googled around a LOT to figure out what Eclipse-editor folks use to have those facilities that are pretty self-evident for an IDE (as opposed to subjective). It seems like a lot of minds wonder the same thing, and we're all looking for someone professional to shine a light on this.

Comment: Try Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web. It has awesome JS support.

Comment: The question itself is already quite helpful, since it provides some of the results you get after googling for an hour or so. And it would be even more helpful, if people were actually allowed to answer. I'd be VERY happy to see some more solutions :-(

Answer (score 1):

If you want  the best JavaScript editor (not free) then go with [PhpStrom](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) from JetBrains

You can use one month trial and this will fulfill all your requirements.

If you want to go with open source then I would recommend you to go with [Aptana](http://aptana.com/).

Hope this solve your problem :)

Comment: phpStorm does provide a free licence for open-source or educational projects.

Comment: Yes phpStrom is not open source but this is really a great tool.

Comment: If you want to go with open source then I would recommend you to go with Aptana which are also good.

Comment: Try Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web. It has awesome JS support.