# How do I properly run the VJET development tools for NodeJS on Eclipse?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, node.js, object-literal, vjet

The default `javascript` editor for `Eclipse` has very poor `outlining` and `code completion`. As a result of this, for any modern javascript application like `ExtJS` or `NodeJS` where you need to write a lot of object literal statements, Eclipse becomes pretty useless. And it is [impossible to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309953/eclipse-javascript-editor-2012-with-full-outliner-support) how to do this properly.

Now I found that [Ebay Open Source](https://www.ebayopensource.org/index.php/VJET/HomePage) seems to have tools that are specifically designed to replace this flaw in the standard editors, both for javascript in general as [for NodeJS specifically](https://www.ebayopensource.org/index.php/VJET/NodeJS).

Installing the normal NodeJS `V8 debugger` on a default `WDT` install of `Eclipse` [is pretty straightforward](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Using-Eclipse-as-Node-Applications-Debugger), and apart from setting up some [script mapping](http://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools/wiki/FeatureDebugOnRealFiles), it's easy to get to work.

But when I tried installing `VJET`, stuff just didn't work. No code assist at all, no debugging anymore, nothing. VJET mode was set as default for debugging and stuff, but when I couldn't get it to work, I couldn't find any option to switch back to normal Eclipse/JS Editor/V8 Debugger either. Even when I removed all VJET stuff, my Eclipse installation was bombed and a complete wipe of the workspace and home configuration + downloads finally fixed this.

So I was hoping that anyone could explain:
**What are the exact steps to getting VJET to work for Node.JS development in Eclipse**, and possibly how can one switch between 'VJET' mode and 'default' mode?