# Running Node.js from Eclipse with VJET

Tags: eclipse, node.js, vjet

I am looking for a workflow - Using Node.js as local web server.

Steps:
1) Edit Node.js server JavaScript from within Eclipse
2) Test the changes with debugging enabled
2) Using VJET to edit Html & JavaScript to the front end.

IS this possible?

I am aware of: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Using-Eclipse-as-Node-Applications-Debugger

VJET does not give you an option to create a "run time"/Web Server when creating the project like standard "Static Web Project".

More specific, I am looking for using Node.js as the runtime for a VJET project or Static Web Project.

Thanks in advance

Regards
Chris

Comment: I guess this would be an answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12072633/how-do-i-properly-run-the-vjet-development-tools-for-nodejs-on-eclipse