# How do I get code completion for Node.js in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, node.js, include, require, code-completion

When developing a `Node.js` application in *Eclipse*, you usually import your own modules with functionality tied to `exports` (append functions) or `module.exports` (allows popular `object literal` notation).

But how do you set this up for code completion in files where you import your module?

**Module**

[image]

As you can see in the `outliner`, *Eclipse* is "aware" of the function:

[image]

Yet importing the module as `tools` doesn't make it's functions available:

[image]

I also tried the oldskool `//@import tools.js` but it doesn't seem to work like this.

How do I get code completion for my own functions in my project?

Comment: Are you using [VJET](http://eclipse.org/vjet/)?

Comment: Nope. I [mentioned it here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309953/eclipse-javascript-editor-2012-with-full-outliner-support) as a suggestion myself, but I [cannot get it to work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12072633/how-do-i-properly-run-the-vjet-development-tools-for-nodejs-on-eclipse).

Comment: hello, use https://c9.io/ it is the best

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@**Jey Keu**: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309953/eclipse-javascript-editor-2012-with-full-outliner-support) has some suggestions towards our mutual dream of code completion, namely:

- Amateras plugin
- JSDT editor
- Aptana Plugin
- SPKET plugin
- VJET plugin

But it was closed by a bunch of people who know nothing about Eclipse. Profiling is the basis of code completion. But they think profiling is unicorns and rainbows and therefore not constructive.

I think, depending on your specific development needs, that `VJET` is your best bet. If you can get it to work without destroying every other function within Eclipse, please share your wizardry in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12072633/how-do-i-properly-run-the-vjet-development-tools-for-nodejs-on-eclipse).

http://eclipse.org/vjet/