# Eclipse IDE is not showing suggestions for node.js

Tags: node.js, eclipse

After installing the node.js plugin for eclipse ide, i tried running a simple `hello world` program in the node.js prespective. When I type **console.** it is not showing any suggestions. Is there any way to make my IDE show suggestions without pressing `ctrl+space` everytime?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get code completion for Node.js in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472901/how-do-i-get-code-completion-for-node-js-in-eclipse)

Comment: See if that link helps you out Prasanth!

Comment: @JGlass thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome - I hope it helped out