# Eclipse freezes on suggestion popup

Tags: eclipse, windows-7, freeze

I am having a problem in Eclipse where it freezes whenever I add a period (to try to bring up the content assist popup with possible methods). I can move the mouse, but the blinking text cursor disappears, I can't switch tabs or save, and I need to use a task manager to close Eclipse. This happens with all Java projects/files.

I have never had a problem like this with Eclipse before, and can't tell what started it. After doing several Google searches, all I found was [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=304718). However, I don't see a solution and am running Windows 7, not Linux. Also, I have never heard of Xulrunner. Does anybody have a solution or explanation? Is it an Eclipse setting, or a problem with my computer?

Error Log: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/101364250/eclipse_freeze.log
When I watched the error view, it seemed to output "Unhandled event loop exception" a lot.

For now, I have disabled the content assist, which seems to fix the problem.
However, this feature is very helpful, so any answers are appreciated!

Comment: Am I the only one with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try opening Preferences and tick "Suspend all validators".

Comment: Finally! Thank you for the answer! Unfortunately, it didn't work. Do you know what is causing this problem?

Comment: The "unhandled event loop" message looks like a generic message, but some searches suggest it is related to Content Assist on JavaScript files. You could try disabling Content Assist for JavaScript maybe? Some further suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14276892/why-do-i-get-message-unhandled-event-loop-exception-java-heap-space-in-eclips

Comment: how did you fix this @nbura

Comment: I don't think I was ever able to fix it, unfortunately :( Not that I'd remember, honestly - 2013 was quite a while ago haha

Answer (score 0):

Try disable the hovers feature:

[eclipse menu: Wndow > Preference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8feM.png)

Comment: why we have to disable ? how to make it work ? why it frezzes ?