# Eclipse oxygen unhandled event loop exception

Tags: java, eclipse

Everytime I click into Eclipse to edit code I get this error, I've tried a lot of fixes and none are working.

[Error Log](https://pastebin.com/WF8qcT1j)

```
pastebin.com/WF8qcT1j
```

Comment: Probably, add more details, like what editor is causing the problem (.java .txt or?). Have you tried to open the file via Eclipse Text Editor - is it giving an error in this case?

Comment: At Least, what programming language do you use? Have you installed any eclipse plugins to have an editor for this language?

Comment: Also, what operating system do you use? I guess, it can be connected with insufficient java heap size. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14276892/why-do-i-get-message-unhandled-event-loop-exception-java-heap-space-in-eclips

Comment: @SergeiSirik It's Java, and I haven't done anything to eclipse. I installed it and used it and it worked for a long long time and now all of sudden its giving me this error. I tried to install "WindowBuilder" because its a solution apparently, but it isn't even showing up when I install it into eclipse.

Comment: Your version of Java is from a different year than your Eclipse installation. Can you update it? Has it been a while since you rebooted?

Comment: I tried the heap size thing,the MaxPermSize isn't in my .ini file. I tried changing the xmx to 2048 instead of 1024. I tried adding the MaxPermSize line and eventually the program wouldn't even start so I had to delete my eclipse folder and install a new one.

Comment: @nitind I just installed the new version because I deleted the old one, I will try to update it.

Comment: no updates available @nitind

Comment: Strange. 144 is the current one for 8.